# How to use printf with variables, strings and new lines to write to a file in one line in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to do a printf of variables, strings and new lines to a file in bash, and in one line. I would of used echo, but echo seems to be interpreted differently and on other questions have recommended printf.

```
NAME="karl"
printf %"s\n" this is $(NAME) hello! > my_file
```

When I do a `cat my_file` I'd like it to look as the following:

```
this
is
karl
hello!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
name="karl"
printf "%s\n" this is "$name" hello! > my_file
```

The only issue with your code was that you were using `$()` (a command substitution) rather than a standard parameter expansion. That said, your format specifier looked strange, as it is normally written `%s` (it still works written your way, because the shell consumes the quotes).

Quotes are always a good idea to prevent word splitting (e.g. spaces in the name would go on separate lines) and glob expansion (a name like `a*` would expand to a list of paths starting with `a`).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the `printf` line with

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g ' <<< "this is ${NAME} hello!" > my_file
```